# How to add two arguments in a template string

Tags: javascript, html

I try to insert in a tablecell a button with an onclick event with two arguments. But I get the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input".

I can't find the error. Do you have any suggestions?

Thank you very much!

```
async function generate_table() {
var tbl = document.getElementById("table");
var tblBody = document.createElement("tbody");

let data = await axios.get("https://www.semmelsemrau.de/getAllEntries");
// creating all cells
for (var i = 0; i < data.data.result.length; i++) {
    // creates a table row
    let dataRow = JSON.stringify(data.data.result[i]);
    console.log(dataRow);
    var row = document.createElement("tr");

    let cell1 = document.createElement("td");
    var cell1Text = document.createTextNode(data.data.result[i].ID);
    cell1.appendChild(cell1Text);
    let cell2 = document.createElement("td");
    var cell2Text = document.createTextNode(data.data.result[i].Geraet);
    cell2.appendChild(cell2Text);
    let cell3 = document.createElement("td");
    var cell3Text = document.createTextNode(data.data.result[i].Number);
    cell3.appendChild(cell3Text);
    let cell4 = document.createElement("td");
    var cell4Text = document.createTextNode(data.data.result[i].Standort);
    cell4.appendChild(cell4Text);
    let cell5 = document.createElement("td");
    var cell5Text = document.createTextNode(data.data.result[i].Ausleihe);
    cell5.appendChild(cell5Text);
    let cell6 = document.createElement("td");
    cell6.className = "imageContainer";
    cell6.innerHTML = `<img class="image" rowid=${data.data.result[i].ID} src=https://www.semmelsemrau.de/${data.data.result[i].Foto}></img>`;
    let cell7 = document.createElement("td");
    cell7.className = "edit";
    cell7.innerHTML = `<button onclick="editRow(${
        (data.data.result[i].ID, dataRow)
    })"><i class="fa fa-edit" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>`;

    row.appendChild(cell1);
    row.appendChild(cell2);
    row.appendChild(cell3);
    row.appendChild(cell4);
    row.appendChild(cell5);
    row.appendChild(cell6);
    row.appendChild(cell7);

    // add the row to the end of the table body
    tblBody.appendChild(row);
}

// put the <tbody> in the <table>
tbl.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", tblBody);
// sets the border attribute of tbl to 2;
tbl.setAttribute("border", "2");
}
```

Comment: Don't do this `onclick="editRow(${variable})"`. Use an event listener instead.

Comment: You can try ```${(data.data.result[i].ID)},${dataRow}``` instead of ```${(data.data.result[i].ID, dataRow)}```

Comment: Don't use `onclick`, then you don't have this problem in the first place. Use `cell7.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => editRow(data.data.result[i].ID, dataRow))` and **change `var i` to `let i` in your loop** otherwise it will evaluate to a wrong value later on because the code runs after you loop is finished!

Comment: and then append it as a child?

Comment: That solved my problem. Thank you very much!